# Special character encoding in HTML attribute of open graph protocol

Tags: c#, character-encoding, html-encode, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to encode special character in html attribute using C# `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`.

When I encode this following string

```
var encode1= HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("Student on  \" On the Rise \"");
```

the encoding generates the correct output, like this:

```
Student on  &quot; On the Rise &quot;
```

The browser encodes the `&` and again and generate wrong encoding as follow

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Student on  &amp;quot; On the Rise &amp;quot;" />
```

How can I tell the browser not to encode the `&` character again?

Comment: You're encoding two times ?

Comment: no i am encoding just one time.

Comment: It seems like twice encoded. Are you using HTML Agility pack, or any other HTML support tools, that may it encode without your knowledge? Try to post the relevant part of your code. *(Minimal verifiable example - how do you create the HTML data?.)*